# are these patents granted or not?

Tags: granted, publication

Were these patents ever granted or not?

This one shows three publications after application but no note of being granted:

https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2009046346A2

Not sure how there was no grant or denial after publication. But I'm not sure of the definition of publication.

This one shows publication, assignment to a company, and then abandonment, but it also is noted as pending in US as of 2016:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US20070041954A1/

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one US patent - [US9,433,646](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9433646B2) - that was granted based on the set of applications related to the publication US20070041954A1. A series of applications were filed that all derived priority from provisional application 60/699,579 filed 07-14-2005. This is the history - (from Public PAIR)

11/486,635 filed on 07-13-2006 which is Abandoned

12/955,755 filed on 11-29-2010 which is Abandoned

**13/688,864 filed on 11-29-2012 which is Patented as 9,433,646**

15/228,849 filed on 08-04-2016 which is Abandoned

PCT/US06/27305 filed on 07-12-2006 which is Published

Publication is not the same as patenting. The last entry is an international patent application. I see in Patentscope that it entered the national stage in Germany but was later withdrawn.

International application publication WO2009046346A2 is by the same inventors but is from a different, later, original filing. It comes from US provisional application 60/977,607 filed 10-04-2007. It does not seem to have entered the national stage anywhere according to PatentScope.